# DJANGO Load/include templates inside base template using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, templates

I am trying to load templates in django using ajax.

I don't want to extend the base template in all other templates as it takes huge processing time.

Hence I am finding a way to load base.html only once and the later requests will just include thier response templates within the base i.e without rendering the base.html again(the header & footer and css stuff).

Is there any way to load other templates within base template using ajax, so that the entire page is not rendered always.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways: you have to avoid using `{% extends "base.html" %}` in your templates and render them using `render_to_string`; after you returned the rendered HTML from your Django view you can insert it where you prefer in the DOM using javascript.

A small snippet example of such an action would be

```
def element_form_ajax(request):
    form = PageForm()
    html = render_to_string('pages/element_form.html',
                            {'form': form},
                            RequestContext(request))
    data = {'form': html}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Now your Ajax call from the webpage gets returned a JSON object with a `form` key containing an HTML form ready to be displayed where you prefer.

Refer to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) as to how to handle CSFR tokens for AJAX calls.

Comment: who says, we need to avoid ``{% extends "base.html" %}`` ?

Comment: Uhm, he did :) If he wants to render only certain sections of the page, I find it appropriate to avoid including `head` sections and whatnot too.

Comment: he will have to use caching anyway, i guess, so why so much worry about small html parts?

Comment: Besides performance, which I also think is not that big of an issue, it will make the site look more modern and pave the way for cleaner interactions.. I'm using this pattern quite a lot lately, you don't believe it's a viable solution?